# Why my node server does not read my fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, request, fetch

I have a middleware that I use to read all my Server requests.

```
const readReq = (req,res,nex)=>{
  console.log('from readReq',req.url);
  next();
}

module.exports = readReq;
```

I have on my client-side a fetch function that I use to get data:

```
const getUserData = async(path,h)=>{
    console.log(path);
    
    let data = await fetch(path,{
        headers:h,
    });
   
    console.log('getUserData',{data});
    console.log('h1',header.get('Authorization'));
    if(data.status === 301)
    {
        cntr++; //Just for testing note a part of the code.
        if(cntr === 2)
        {
            console.log({cntr})
            return;
        }
        await getRefreshTocken();
        console.log('h2',header.get('Authorization'));
        getUserData('mylst',header);
    }
    try{
        let res = await data.json();
        console.log(res);
        genarateMovies(res.userMovies);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

my problem is that the middleware reads my request when my **path** parameter equals any value except the value of my get request. but when my **path** parameter equals the path of my get request that I need my middleware can't read it. and the fetch has a status of 301.

my request that I want to fetch:

```
app.use('/mylst',require('./routers/getUserMovies'));
```

Comment: It looks like the browser got the [301 response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) in the past and stored the new URL. "Moved permanently" means that the browser auto-redirects.

Comment: This is right,  thanks. I solve it by disabling the cache, from google browser settings, but is that really solve the problem. If a client has cacheing in his browser this can make an error.  how can to avoid this property?

Comment: Why would you disable this functionality? Why would you send "Moved permanently" in the first place? Don't send this response code for temporary redirects. Use [HTTP response code 302 "Moved temporarily"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) instead.